# SSRS Subtracting union columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services, union, ssrs-2012

I've hit a bit of a wall while building a report...

This is my underlying query

```
SELECT        'unionCol1Name' AS SRC, col1,col2,col3
FROM            tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT        'unionCol2Name', col1,col2,col3
FROM            tbl2
```

I have a matrix report that displays both of these union columns but only when viewed. My problem is that I need to subtract one column from the other but I'm having difficulty defining the columns as they're in a union.

I have a feeling there's a way to distinguish between the two union columns that are generated once the report has run, through the textbox expression field in the report design.

The report looks like this once previewed:

```
union1 results    Union2 results
78                   54
12                   24
51                   12
63                   43
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: sample data and expected resultset plz

Comment: should these then not be joined as opposed to unioned? subtracting columns is what it sounds like what you want to do

Comment: Yeah, that's what I need to do. However joining the two tables together in separate columns would create NULL values in some of the rows in the datasets.

Comment: Why not use two separate queries?

Comment: Because that would yield two seperate datasets and you can't do that in an ssrs martix that is using a single table. Hence why I did the union.

Comment: Perhaps this is a little clearer:

I need to specify the union columns in the expression field text box in order to subtract them from each other.

Comment: Then you need to have different column names, and the way to do that is with a JOIN.  Explain why the NULL values will occur and why it's a problem, and what values should be returned instead.   Your question isn't very clear about your requirements.

Comment: I just need to subtract two columns.
The problem is that they're a union column in the report (both columns are into one)

How do I say in the epxression box I want =Fields!unioncolumn1.value -  Fields!unioncolumn2.value

Comment: You already said that, and I already told you, you need to join the two tables, so that you have two different columns.   You can't do this with a single column, which is what a UNION produces.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column with the **ColumnType** to differentiate the two.

```
SELECT        'unionCol1Name' AS SRC, col1,col2,col3, 1 as ColumnType 
FROM            tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT        'unionCol2Name', col1,col2,col3, 2 as ColumnType 
FROM            tbl2
```

Then in your SSRS expression:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!ColumnType.Value = 1, Fields!SRC.Value, 0) - SUM(IIF(Fields!ColumnType.Value = 2, Fields!SRC.Value, 0)
```